# Error in Ctree_Control as unused argument

Tags: r

While I was trying to use Ctree_Control,i am getting some error as Unused argument.

```
 MyTree2 <- ctree(Class ~., 
                  control=ctree_control(teststat = c("quadratic", "maximum"), 
                                        splitstat = c("quadratic", "maximum"), 
                                        mincriterion = 0.9999), 
                   data = train_data)
```

> Error in ctree_control(teststat = c("quadratic", "maximum"), splitstat = >c("quadratic",  : 
>    unused argument (splitstat = c("quadratic", "maximum"))

```
MyTree2 <- ctree(Class ~., 
                 control=ctree_control(teststat = c("quadratic", "maximum"), 
                                       splitstat = c("quadratic", "maximum"), 
                                       mincriterion = 0.9999), 
                 data = train_data)
```

> Error in ctree_control(teststat = c("quadratic", "maximum"), splitstat = >c("quadratic",  : 
>    unused argument (splitstat = c("quadratic", "maximum"))

```
MyTree2 <- ctree(Class ~., 
                 control=ctree_control(teststat = c("quadratic", "maximum"), 
                                       splitstat = c("quadratic", "maximum"), 
                                       mincriterion = 0.9999), 
                 data = train_data)
```

> Error in ctree_control(teststat = c("quadratic", "maximum"), splitstat = >c("quadratic",  : 
>    unused argument (splitstat = c("quadratic", "maximum"))

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using **"party"** package then some parameters of  the ctree_control function like **splitstat** will not work, If you want to use individual trees (as opposed to forests), then the **"partykit"** package is recommended because it contains much improved re-implementations of ctree().

```
install.packages("partykit")
library(partykit)
MyTree2 <- ctree(Class ~.,
                 control=ctree_control(teststat = c("quadratic", "maximum"), 
                                       splitstat = c("quadratic", "maximum"), 
                                       mincriterion = 0.9999),
                 data = train_data)
```